# OpenGL cannot find any v3.3 functions in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, graphics, opengl-3

What I have included (other than c++ standard library headers):

`#include <GL/glut.h>`

And my compiling command include `-lGL -lGLU -lglut`

However, when I compile my code, I got `'xxx' was not declared in this scope` for glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, and all other 3.3 functions.

I tried to include a few other files such as GL3.h or glew.h, but they do no help: either the error is still there, or more errors popped up.

What am I missing to include?

Answer (score 1):

GLUT/FreeGLUT serve as utility libraries to create and maintain an OpenGL context bound to a certain window. However, resolving function calls to the OpenGL API requires libraries like glew. Therefore, including glew.h and **linking** with -lglew is the right way to go here. Could you please post the occuring errors when including glew.h?